# Creating an object not parallel arrays

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get get "arrToys" and "arrNames" to be next to each other so they are in one object but I am not sure how to do this, I am able to get them parallel with each other but I was told I'm not allowed to do that so could someone show me please. Thank you

```
    function start() {
    document.getElementById("task").innerHTML="Task 8";
    var arrNames = [];
    var vName = "";
    var vToys = "";
    vName = prompt("Enter dog name (leave blank to stop)");
    vToys = parseInt(prompt("Enter dogs toys (leave blank to stop)"));
    while (vName.length > 0) {
        arrNames.push(vName);
        arrNames.push(vToys);
        vName = prompt("Enter dog name (leave blank to stop)");
        vToys = parseInt(prompt("Enter dogs toys (leave blank to stop)"));
    }
    var name = function name(dogs) {
        return dogs.map(function(dogName, index) {
            return "Dog "+(index+1)+": "+ dogName;
        });
    };
    var Tname = function Tname(toys) {
        return toys.map(function(toyNum) {
            return "No. of toys: " + toyNum;
        });
    };
    arrNames.forEach(function(entry) {
    var vOutput = "Dog names and No. of toys: <br/>" + name(arrNames).join("<br/>") + Tname(arrNames).join("<br/>");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=vOutput;
    });
}
```

Comment: Arrays ARE Objects in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the feedback you're getting is that instead of parallel arrays, you should be using an array of objects. (And that's good feedback.)

So you'd have one array:

```
var stuff = [];
```

And then you get a dog name and list of toys:

```
name = prompt("Enter dog name (leave blank to stop)");
toys = parseInt(prompt("Enter dogs toys (leave blank to stop)"));
```

And then push an object onto the array if those are given:

```
stuff.push({
    name: name,
    toys: toys
});
```

It looks like you're supposed to do some processing on them afterward. Inside an `Array#forEach` or `Array#map`, you'd be dealing with an object with `name` and `toys` properties. E.g.:

```
stuff.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry.name + " has these toys: " + entry.toys);
});
```

---

I've intentionally **not** written complete code for you here, just pointing you at what to do an the necessary parts to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am gertting a little confused, for the "stuff.push" part am I just suposed to put "vName" and "vToys", not sure what else I would put? Also for the last part that is for my "var vOutput" yeah or am I wrong?

Comment: I have updated my code so you can see what I have done